# takeRightWhile() method in scala

Tags: string, scala

I might be missing something but recently I came across a task to get last symbols according to some condition. For example I have a string: `"this_is_separated_values_5"`. Now I want to extract `5` as `Int`.

Note: number of parts separated by `_` is not defined.

If I would have a method `takeRightWhile(f: Char => Boolean)` on a string it would be trivial: `takeRightWhile(ch => ch != '_')`. Moreover it would be efficient: a straightforward implementation would actually involve finding the last index of `_` and taking a substring while the use of this method would save first step and provide better average time complexity.

**UPDATE:** Guys, all the variations of `str.reverse.takeWhile(_!='_').reverse` are quite inefficient as you actually use additional `O(n)` space. If you want to implement method `takeRightWhile` efficiently you could iterate starting from the right, accumulating result in string builder of whatever else, and returning the result. I am asking about this kind of method, not implementation which was already described and declined in the question itself.

**Question:** Does this kind of method exist in scala standard library? If no, is there method combination from the standard library to achieve the same in minimum amount of lines?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
str.reverse.takeWhile(_!='_').reverse
```

**Update**

You can go from right to left with following expression using foldRight:

```
str.toList.foldRight(List.empty[Char]) {
  case (item, acc) => item::acc
}
```

Here you need to check condition and stop adding items after condition met. For this you can pass a flag to accumulated value:

```
val (_, list) = str.toList.foldRight((false, List.empty[Char])) {
  case (item, (false, list)) if item!='_' => (false, item::list)
  case (_,    (_,     list))              => (true, list)
}
val res = list.mkString.toInt
```

This solution is even more inefficient then solution with double reverse:

1. Implementation of foldRight uses combination of List reverse and foldLeft
2. You cannot break foldRight execution, so you need flag to skip all items after condition met

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please see update of the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for update. At least it does not create new string so it is more efficient than previous solution. Maybe simplify it to tail recursion and StringBuilder to improve time complexity (in other words terminate foldRight)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this:

```
val s = "string_with_following_number_42"
s.split("_").reverse.head
// res:String = 42
```

This is a naive attempt and by no means optimized. What it does is splitting the `String` into an `Array` of `String`s, reverses it and takes the first element. Note that, because the reversing happens after the splitting, the order of the characters is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However split is even worse than .reverse.take.reverse approach

Comment: Why is that? As I thought, split and reverse both need to iterate over the whole String, which would be O(n).

Comment: From time complexity you are right, but both split and reverse result additional n space footprint

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure about the problem you are facing. My understanding is that you want have a string of format `xxx_xxx_xx_...._xxx_123` and you want to extract the part at the end as `Int`.

```
import scala.util.Try

val yourStr = "xxx_xxx_xxx_xx...x_xxxxx_123"

val yourInt = yourStr.split('_').last.toInt

// But remember that the above is unsafe so you may want to take it as Option

val yourIntOpt = Try(yourStr.split('_').last.toInt).toOption
```

Or... lets say your requirement is to collect a `right-suffix` till some boolean condition remains `true`.

```
import scala.util.Try

val yourStr = "xxx_xxx_xxx_xx...x_xxxxx_123"

val rightSuffix =  yourStr.reverse.takeWhile(c => c != '_').reverse

val yourInt = rightSuffix.toInt

// but above is unsafe so
val yourIntOpt = Try(righSuffix.toInt).toOption
```

Comment if your requirement is different from this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However split is even worse than .reverse.take.reverse approach. Thanks for pointing to try however.

Comment: Actually split approach is better if your requirement is to split on some particular character. But if you need to collect the suffix based on some other boolean condition then you need something like `reverse.take.reverse`

Answer (score -1):

You can use StringBuilder and lastIndexWhere.

```
val str = "this_is_separated_values_5"
val sb = new StringBuilder(str)
val lastIdx = sb.lastIndexWhere(ch => ch != '_')
val lastCh = str.charAt(lastIdx)
```

Comment: Did you test this? Because it doesn't work if there's more than one character after the final `_` - OP clearly wants the rest of the string, not the last character or it would just be a matter of getting the last character!. There's also no need for the the StringBuilder, `lastIndexWhere` works on String.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I misunderstood the question. I first found `lastIndexWhere` in `StringBuilder` and didn't check `StringOps`. Thanks for pointing out them.